# Why is Wayland comparatively unstable (crashing every single app)?

Tags: crash, gnome-shell-extension, wayland

Could someone explain why, when I run 20.10 with Wayland instead of X, the desktop seems so unstable? By unstable I don't mean the frequency of crashes (although that too has been significant) but instead that when something goes wrong suddenly *every single application* is terminated and I find myself back on the login screen.

I've used Windows for 20+ years, macOS for 8 and have been checking out Ubuntu without Wayland for 12, but can't ever recall having had crashes of this severity this frequently on any of them. I realize it's architecture related but in all honesty I don't know enough about the underlying architecture to even draw a simple diagram of it, not to mention pointing out the problem in it. Is it a difficult problem?

What I could figure out from my specific crashes was that even something as trivial as a careless **line of javascript in a Gnome extension** could be the cause. This left me wondering why something called an "extension", and generally distributed in what could be described as a carefree manner in an extension gallery on a website (if not carefree then at least *inviting* -- reminiscent of a browser extension gallery), is allowed to bring down every single application if it happens to contain a bug. Hence this question.

Now, you might say that it's up to me to install or not install, but the extension that brought down my system repeatedly is the desktop icons extension shipped with Ubuntu, so I didn't even choose to install that particular one. I can only imagine that stability would worsen if throwing 3rd party extensions into the mix.

I did try to search for this and I found some bug report for Fedora that recognized the problem, but I couldn't really put that discussion into context. I couldn't even tell if it was being worked on, which would've been nice to know since at present I don't feel at ease using Ubuntu as a desktop OS and would've liked to know whether that might change.

Comment: Relevant: [Ubuntu developers discussing their own Gnome Shell extension woes](https://discourse.ubuntu.com/t/removal-of-gnome-shell-extension-from-universe-and-stop-auto-syncs/18437). The Gnome Shell extensions gallery/website is maintained by Gnome, so do feel free to file extension bugs with Gnome. They cannot fix problems that they don't know about.

Comment: @user535733 Thank you, I have already filed a bug about one of the crashes I experience, which is how I could draw the conclusion about extensions that I did in the question, and which led to asking it.